# Using SetProperty/Dlookup macro to autofill

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am trying to set up a macro and expression to update a form field when an existing record is selected in a different field. Specifically I have a drop down on my form that allows the user to select a "request" object from my request table. When they select it, it automatically fills the projCourseID field with the corresponding reqCourseID from the request object.

The way I have it set up now is to run a SetProperty macro AfterUpdate on the reqID dropdown. I have the macro filled out like this:

> Control Name: projCourseID
>   Property: Value
>   Value =DLookUp("[reqCourseID]","Training Requests","[reqID] =" & [Forms]![New Project]![reqID])

reqID is the primary key to Training Requests table. When I try to run this I get a 2950 error. I feel like I am missing something small and obvious. Wjat am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If other things are okay, I think you are missing `Single Quote (')` in criteria part. see below expression.

```
Value =DLookUp("[reqCourseID]","Training Requests","[reqID] ='" & [Forms]![New Project]![reqID] & "'")
```

Remember in `DLookUP` function criteria use `variant` data type. So, you have to use `Single Quote (')`

Comment: However for some reason when I try to do almost the exact same thing in a different form the error pops up again: <br/> >  Value=DLookUp("[projTarget]","Project","[projID] ='" & [Forms]![New Task]![projID] & "'")'

Comment: Its showing an extra `Single quote` after bracket. You should define a `variant` type variable, then use that variable as criteria rather than `[Forms]![New Task]![projID]` Do you check other codes? Can you please put more codes here? So that we can check.